# Delphi FMX: Text3D on TModel3D (Position and Rotation)

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have a 3D-Object described with `N` .obj-Files. For example a cube is described with 6 .obj-Files. I load every obj-File into a `TModel3D`:

```
files := TDirectory.GetFiles(aDirectory, '*.obj');
for I := 0 to Length(files) - 1 do begin
Self.Add(TModel3D.Create(nil));
Self.Items[Self.Count - 1].Parent := nil;
Self.Items[Self.Count - 1].Position.X := 0;
Self.Items[Self.Count - 1].Position.Y := 0;
Self.Items[Self.Count - 1].Position.Z := 0;
Self.Items[Self.Count - 1].TagString := 'File: ' + ExtractFileName(files[I]);
Self.Items[Self.Count - 1].HitTest := True;

Self.Items[Self.Count - 1].WrapMode := TMeshWrapMode.Original;

Self.Items[Self.Count - 1].LoadFromFile(files[I]);
```

It looks like this:

[image: 3d cube in fmx]

Now I want to add a text on every surface -> so I create a `TText3D` for every `TModel3D`:

```
Self.Items[Self.Count - 1].FText := TText3D.Create(Self.Items[Self.Count - 1]);
Self.Items[Self.Count - 1].FText.Parent := Self.Items[Self.Count - 1];
Self.Items[Self.Count - 1].FText.Text := (I + 1).ToString;
//
Self.Items[Self.Count - 1].FText.WordWrap := False;
//
Self.Items[Self.Count - 1].FText.Stretch := False;
Self.Items[Self.Count - 1].FText.Font.Size := 0.002;
Self.Items[Self.Count - 1].FText.Depth := 0.01;
Self.Items[Self.Count - 1].FText.Height := 0.2;
Self.Items[Self.Count - 1].FText.Width := 0.5;
Self.Items[Self.Count - 1].FText.scale.X := 1;
Self.Items[Self.Count - 1].FText.scale.Y := 1;
Self.Items[Self.Count - 1].FText.WrapMode := TMeshWrapMode.Fit;

Self.Items[Self.Count - 1].FText.RotationAngle.X := Self.Items[Self.Count - 1].MeshCollection[0].RotationAngle.X;
Self.Items[Self.Count - 1].FText.RotationAngle.Y := Self.Items[Self.Count - 1].MeshCollection[0].RotationAngle.Y;
Self.Items[Self.Count - 1].FText.RotationAngle.Z := Self.Items[Self.Count - 1].MeshCollection[0].RotationAngle.Z;

Self.Items[Self.Count - 1].FText.Position.X := Self.Items[Self.Count - 1].MeshCollection[0].Position.X;
Self.Items[Self.Count - 1].FText.Position.Y := Self.Items[Self.Count - 1].MeshCollection[0].Position.Y;
Self.Items[Self.Count - 1].FText.Position.Z := Self.Items[Self.Count - 1].MeshCollection[0].Position.Z;
end;
```

Now it looks like this:

[image: 3d cube with numbers]

The problem is, that I need to change the `rotationAngle` of the text for every `TText3D` in comparison of the `TModel3D`. I don't know how to calculate the rotation, maybe with the `"faceNormals"`?

This is how it should look like (I changed the `rotationAngle` manually):
[image: 3d cube with numbers in correct position / angle]

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
My method to add a description for every model was wrong. I found a solution here: [FireMonkey ViewPort procedure calculated differently world to screen on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71423196/firemonkey-viewport-procedure-calculated-differently-world-to-screen-on-mac)

With the function "WorldToScreen" i was able to add a description for every model.